# Error on Image Fading with links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to make transitions between images through links. I tried the **'Demo 6'** from [this](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/) page. But it didn't work at all, and I did all the steps shown in the tutorial page. This is the link of my testing website (danithemes.fanscity.eu/shugar)

Here you have the code I'm using (It's the same from the tutorial page, but just in case...)

**CSS CODE:**

```
p#cf7_controls {
  text-align:center;
}
#cf7_controls span {
  padding-right:2em;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#cf7 {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto 10px;
}
#cf7 img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  opacity:0;
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

#cf7 img.opaque {
  opacity:1;
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=1);
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="cf7" class="shadow">
  <img class='opaque' src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Birdman.jpg" />
  <img src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Birdman.jpg;" />
  <img src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Birdman.jpg;" />
  <img src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Birdman.jpg;" />
</div>
<p id="cf7_controls">
  <span class="selected">Image 1</span>
  <span>Image 2</span>
  <span>Image 3</span>
  <span>Image 4</span>
</p>
```

**JS CODE**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cf7_controls").on('click', 'span', function() {
    $("#cf7 img").removeClass("opaque");

    var newImage = $(this).index();

    $("#cf7 img").eq(newImage).addClass("opaque");

    $("#cf7_controls span").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  });
});
</script>
```

My question is: What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Tested and works just fine. Have you included jquery library? You also have to remove `;` from image paths.

Comment: @emmanuel No I didn't, how can I do that? Please I need to know. And thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is in your HTML code:

```
<div id="cf7" class="shadow">
  <img class='opaque' src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Birdman.jpg" />
  <img src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Birdman.jpg;" />
  <img src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Birdman.jpg;" />
  <img src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Birdman.jpg;" />
</div>
<p id="cf7_controls">
  <span class="selected">Image 1</span>
  <span>Image 2</span>
  <span>Image 3</span>
  <span>Image 4</span>
</p>
```

You are using the same image "http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Birdman.jpg", which does not make sense, and you wont see a change, just change the other images path.

```
<div id="cf7" class="shadow">
  <img class='opaque' src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Birdman.jpg" />
  <img src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/X.jpg;" />
  <img src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Y.jpg;" />
  <img src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Z.jpg;" />
</div>
<p id="cf7_controls">
  <span class="selected">Image 1</span>
  <span>Image 2</span>
  <span>Image 3</span>
  <span>Image 4</span>
</p>
```

You will have to include this line in the HTML head section.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

See it [LIVE](http://jsfiddle.net/37t3f3cu/).

Answer (score 0):

@Abdelrahman has the right answer. You simply need to use other images than your birdman image. I've made a jsfiddle that uses the same image but different width:
http://jsfiddle.net/lsubirana/uzxt21yh/

```
<div id="cf7" class="shadow">
  <img class='opaque' src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Birdman.jpg" />
  <img src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Birdman.jpg" width="350" />
  <img src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Birdman.jpg"  width="250" />
  <img src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Birdman.jpg"  width="150" />
</div>
```